# VBA Regex only returns the last match

Tags: regex, vba, ms-word

I'm trying to find **all** occurrences of terms that are found in quotes inside brackets ("TERM TO BE FOUND"), whether there are other words in the brackets or not (this is also a "TERM TO BE FOUND").

The content of my ActiveDocument is:

```
This is a ("Test") and another (second "Test2")
```

My code is:

```
Dim regEx As Object
Dim matchCollection As Object
Dim extractedString As String
Dim match As Object
Dim RealQ
Dim n As Integer

RealQ = Chr(34)

Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
With regEx
  .IgnoreCase = IgnoreCase
  .Global = True
  .MultiLine = True
  .Pattern = "\(.*" & RealQ & "(.*)" & RealQ & "\)"
End With

Set matchCollection = regEx.Execute(ActiveDocument.Content.Text)

extractedString = ""

For Each match In matchCollection

    Debug.Print (match.submatches(0))

Next
```

The above only finds the **last occurrence**, i.e. "Test2". What am I missing?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: The reason for that is a greedy dot after `\(`. You should extract all substrings between parentheses first, then extract the strings inside quotes from those matches. It looks like some SQL query, you should consider writing a parser for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this task using the wildcard search in Word itself without needing to invoke Regexp.  The code below will return a scripting.dictionary of range objects from which you can extract text, or with a very minor tweak just return the captured texts.  The key function allows you to define which sets of parentheses you want to use and also which characters you wish to use for the quotes.  In the test case below I have used the characters for smart quotes in word.

The test text I used was

```
Blah blah blah (blah "Text 1" blah) blah blah blah Blah blah blah (blah “Text 2” blah) Blah blah blah (blah “Text 3” blah) Blah blah blah (blah “Text 4” blah)
```

Which gives an output of

```
Text 2
Text 3
Text 4
```

because the first set of quotes are not smart quotes.  You don't say if you just need to extract text or find the text and then process it inside the Word document in some way, hence my first option of returning the Word.Ranges of the found text.  The tweak to get just the text is provided in the comments to the function.

The code below raises no code inspections from the fantastic RubberDuck add in.

```
Public Sub testGetTextInQuotesInBrackets()

Dim myTexts As Scripting.Dictionary

    Set myTexts = _
        GetTextInQuotesInBrackets _
        ( _
            "(,)", _
            ChrW$(&H201C) & "," & ChrW$(&H201D), _
            ActiveDocument.StoryRanges(wdMainTextStory) _
        )

    Dim myItem As Variant
    For Each myItem In myTexts

        Debug.Print myTexts.Item(myItem).Text
        ' if just the text was collected
        'Debug.Print myItem

    Next

End Sub

'@Description("Returns a scripting.Dictionary of long vs word.range objects)
Function GetTextInQuotesInBrackets _
( _
    ByVal ipBrackets As String, _
    ByVal ipQuotes As String, _
    ByRef ipRange As Word.Range _
) As Scripting.Dictionary


    Dim myTextRanges As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set myTextRanges = New Scripting.Dictionary

    Dim myBrackets As Variant
    myBrackets = Split(ipBrackets, ",")

    Dim myQuotes As Variant
    myQuotes = Split(ipQuotes, ",")

    With ipRange

        With .Find

            .ClearFormatting
            .Text = "[" & myBrackets(0) & "]*[" & myQuotes(0) & "]*[" & myQuotes(1) & "]" ' is there any need to process the following closing bracket
            .MatchWildcards = True
            .Wrap = wdFindStop

        End With

        Do While .Find.Execute

            Dim myFoundRange As Word.Range
            Set myFoundRange = .Duplicate
            With myFoundRange

                .MoveStartUntil cset:=myQuotes(0)
                ' Select the text within the quotes
                .MoveStart Count:=1
                .MoveEnd Count:=-1


            End With

            myTextRanges.Add myTextRanges.Count, myFoundRange
            ' Alternatively, if you just need the text
            'myTextRanges.add myTextRanges.count, myFoundRange.Text
            .Start = myFoundRange.End + 2
            .End = ipRange.End

        Loop

    End With

    Set GetTextInQuotesInBrackets = myTextRanges

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need RegEx for this! It can all be done with Word's own *wildcard* Find tools. For example:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim StrFnd As String, i As Long
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "\(*[^34][!\)]@[^34]*\)"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Forward = True
    .Format = False
    .Execute
  End With
  Do While .Find.Found
    i = i + 1
    StrFnd = StrFnd & vbCr & Split(.Text, """")(1)
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .Find.Execute
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox i & " instances found:" & StrFnd
End Sub
```

More complex code could be used to handle content with smart quotes also.